# Linux kernel:Register a handler for a specific UDP port traffic?

Tags: linux, sockets, event-handling, linux-kernel, udp

I am writing a tunnelling kernel module for which i want to register my own  handler for a specific UDP port. What is the best possible way to do this? The idea is to register that handler so that when the traffic on that port arrives, the linux stack will call my handler.

[Edit1]

A way through the socket API is to bind to a socket like this

```
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
sin.sin_port = htons(my_port);

err = kernel_bind(rcv_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&sin,
        sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

udp_sk(rcv_socket->sk)->encap_rcv = my_handler;
```

The problem is that this socket is associated with `INADDR_ANY` which corresponds to any of the host IPs on the machine. I want to do this this for ANY IP that comes in the packet? How can that be achieved?

Sockets cannot be used in this case i think, since ANY IP would mean that in the stack the packet goes through the `ip_forward` path instead of `ip_local_delivery`. There will be no socket made for such a packet. How to achieve it under this condition?

Comment: Why do you need to do this in kernel mode?  The requirement you have described would seem to be an entirely normal thing for a user-mode application using the sockets API to do...

Comment: @ChrisStratton I understand your concern but this requirement is part of a bigger picture that needs to be built inside the kernel.

Comment: I'm not a super expert but i think you can't get packets that needs forwarding with a socket listening for transport layer data. What about a raw socket working at ethernet level? I know it could be a pain =(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know the relative kernel level functions but what i suggest is bind to a RAW SOCKET listening for layer 2 frames, with a further filter for ip packets.

Like this:

`fd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP));`

then it's up to you to dissect the frame and extract only udp packets you need.

Working at layer 2 should grants you the deliver of 100% of ip packets traveling through your host.

Answer (score 1):

**TO DOWN VOTER: Please comment on why you down voted this tried and tested answer?**

The following example is helpful. You may modify the example by adding filters as deemed necessary.

For UDP the following change needs to be present in the example below

`sock_raw = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_UDP);`

http://www.binarytides.com/packet-sniffer-code-in-c-using-linux-sockets-bsd/
http://www.binarytides.com/packet-sniffer-code-in-c-using-linux-sockets-bsd-part-2/ [relevance]

I list the code FYI

```
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<stdio.h> //For standard things
#include<stdlib.h>    //malloc
#include<string.h>    //strlen

#include<netinet/ip_icmp.h>   //Provides declarations for icmp header
#include<netinet/udp.h>   //Provides declarations for udp header
#include<netinet/tcp.h>   //Provides declarations for tcp header
#include<netinet/ip.h>    //Provides declarations for ip header
#include<netinet/if_ether.h>  //For ETH_P_ALL
#include<net/ethernet.h>  //For ether_header
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void ProcessPacket(unsigned char* , int);
void print_ip_header(unsigned char* , int);
void print_tcp_packet(unsigned char * , int );
void print_udp_packet(unsigned char * , int );
void print_icmp_packet(unsigned char* , int );
void PrintData (unsigned char* , int);

FILE *logfile;
struct sockaddr_in source,dest;
int tcp=0,udp=0,icmp=0,others=0,igmp=0,total=0,i,j; 

int main()
{
    int saddr_size , data_size;
    struct sockaddr saddr;

    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *) malloc(65536); //Its Big!

    logfile=fopen("log.txt","w");
    if(logfile==NULL) 
    {
        printf("Unable to create log.txt file.");
    }
    printf("Starting...\n");

    int sock_raw = socket( AF_PACKET , SOCK_RAW , htons(ETH_P_ALL)) ;
    //setsockopt(sock_raw , SOL_SOCKET , SO_BINDTODEVICE , "eth0" , strlen("eth0")+ 1 );

    if(sock_raw < 0)
    {
        //Print the error with proper message
        perror("Socket Error");
        return 1;
    }
    while(1)
    {
        saddr_size = sizeof saddr;
        //Receive a packet
        data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 65536 , 0 , &saddr , (socklen_t*)&saddr_size);
        if(data_size <0 )
        {
            printf("Recvfrom error , failed to get packets\n");
            return 1;
        }
        //Now process the packet
        ProcessPacket(buffer , data_size);
    }
    close(sock_raw);
    printf("Finished");
    return 0;
}

void ProcessPacket(unsigned char* buffer, int size)
{
    //Get the IP Header part of this packet , excluding the ethernet header
    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr*)(buffer + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
    ++total;
    switch (iph->protocol) //Check the Protocol and do accordingly...
    {
        case 1:  //ICMP Protocol
            ++icmp;
            print_icmp_packet( buffer , size);
            break;

        case 2:  //IGMP Protocol
            ++igmp;
            break;

        case 6:  //TCP Protocol
            ++tcp;
            print_tcp_packet(buffer , size);
            break;

        case 17: //UDP Protocol
            ++udp;
            print_udp_packet(buffer , size);
            break;

        default: //Some Other Protocol like ARP etc.
            ++others;
            break;
    }
    printf("TCP : %d   UDP : %d   ICMP : %d   IGMP : %d   Others : %d   Total : %d\r", tcp , udp , icmp , igmp , others , total);
}

void print_ethernet_header(unsigned char* Buffer, int Size)
{
    struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *)Buffer;

    fprintf(logfile , "\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "Ethernet Header\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Destination Address : %.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X \n", eth->h_dest[0] , eth->h_dest[1] , eth->h_dest[2] , eth->h_dest[3] , eth->h_dest[4] , eth->h_dest[5] );
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Source Address      : %.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X \n", eth->h_source[0] , eth->h_source[1] , eth->h_source[2] , eth->h_source[3] , eth->h_source[4] , eth->h_source[5] );
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Protocol            : %u \n",(unsigned short)eth->h_proto);
}

void print_ip_header(unsigned char* Buffer, int Size)
{
    print_ethernet_header(Buffer , Size);

    unsigned short iphdrlen;

    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)(Buffer  + sizeof(struct ethhdr) );
    iphdrlen =iph->ihl*4;

    memset(&source, 0, sizeof(source));
    source.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->saddr;

    memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
    dest.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->daddr;

    fprintf(logfile , "\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "IP Header\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-IP Version        : %d\n",(unsigned int)iph->version);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-IP Header Length  : %d DWORDS or %d Bytes\n",(unsigned int)iph->ihl,((unsigned int)(iph->ihl))*4);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Type Of Service   : %d\n",(unsigned int)iph->tos);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-IP Total Length   : %d  Bytes(Size of Packet)\n",ntohs(iph->tot_len));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Identification    : %d\n",ntohs(iph->id));
    //fprintf(logfile , "   |-Reserved ZERO Field   : %d\n",(unsigned int)iphdr->ip_reserved_zero);
    //fprintf(logfile , "   |-Dont Fragment Field   : %d\n",(unsigned int)iphdr->ip_dont_fragment);
    //fprintf(logfile , "   |-More Fragment Field   : %d\n",(unsigned int)iphdr->ip_more_fragment);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-TTL      : %d\n",(unsigned int)iph->ttl);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Protocol : %d\n",(unsigned int)iph->protocol);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Checksum : %d\n",ntohs(iph->check));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Source IP        : %s\n",inet_ntoa(source.sin_addr));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Destination IP   : %s\n",inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
}

void print_tcp_packet(unsigned char* Buffer, int Size)
{
    unsigned short iphdrlen;

    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)( Buffer  + sizeof(struct ethhdr) );
    iphdrlen = iph->ihl*4;

    struct tcphdr *tcph=(struct tcphdr*)(Buffer + iphdrlen + sizeof(struct ethhdr));

    int header_size =  sizeof(struct ethhdr) + iphdrlen + tcph->doff*4;

    fprintf(logfile , "\n\n***********************TCP Packet*************************\n");  

    print_ip_header(Buffer,Size);

    fprintf(logfile , "\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "TCP Header\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Source Port      : %u\n",ntohs(tcph->source));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Destination Port : %u\n",ntohs(tcph->dest));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Sequence Number    : %u\n",ntohl(tcph->seq));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Acknowledge Number : %u\n",ntohl(tcph->ack_seq));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Header Length      : %d DWORDS or %d BYTES\n" ,(unsigned int)tcph->doff,(unsigned int)tcph->doff*4);
    //fprintf(logfile , "   |-CWR Flag : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcph->cwr);
    //fprintf(logfile , "   |-ECN Flag : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcph->ece);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Urgent Flag          : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcph->urg);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Acknowledgement Flag : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcph->ack);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Push Flag            : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcph->psh);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Reset Flag           : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcph->rst);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Synchronise Flag     : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcph->syn);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Finish Flag          : %d\n",(unsigned int)tcph->fin);
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Window         : %d\n",ntohs(tcph->window));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Checksum       : %d\n",ntohs(tcph->check));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Urgent Pointer : %d\n",tcph->urg_ptr);
    fprintf(logfile , "\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "                        DATA Dump                         ");
    fprintf(logfile , "\n");

    fprintf(logfile , "IP Header\n");
    PrintData(Buffer,iphdrlen);

    fprintf(logfile , "TCP Header\n");
    PrintData(Buffer+iphdrlen,tcph->doff*4);

    fprintf(logfile , "Data Payload\n");    
    PrintData(Buffer + header_size , Size - header_size );

    fprintf(logfile , "\n###########################################################");
}

void print_udp_packet(unsigned char *Buffer , int Size)
{

    unsigned short iphdrlen;

    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)(Buffer +  sizeof(struct ethhdr));
    iphdrlen = iph->ihl*4;

    struct udphdr *udph = (struct udphdr*)(Buffer + iphdrlen  + sizeof(struct ethhdr));

    int header_size =  sizeof(struct ethhdr) + iphdrlen + sizeof udph;

    fprintf(logfile , "\n\n***********************UDP Packet*************************\n");

    print_ip_header(Buffer,Size);           

    fprintf(logfile , "\nUDP Header\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Source Port      : %d\n" , ntohs(udph->source));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Destination Port : %d\n" , ntohs(udph->dest));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-UDP Length       : %d\n" , ntohs(udph->len));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-UDP Checksum     : %d\n" , ntohs(udph->check));

    fprintf(logfile , "\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "IP Header\n");
    PrintData(Buffer , iphdrlen);

    fprintf(logfile , "UDP Header\n");
    PrintData(Buffer+iphdrlen , sizeof udph);

    fprintf(logfile , "Data Payload\n");    

    //Move the pointer ahead and reduce the size of string
    PrintData(Buffer + header_size , Size - header_size);

    fprintf(logfile , "\n###########################################################");
}

void print_icmp_packet(unsigned char* Buffer , int Size)
{
    unsigned short iphdrlen;

    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)(Buffer  + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
    iphdrlen = iph->ihl * 4;

    struct icmphdr *icmph = (struct icmphdr *)(Buffer + iphdrlen  + sizeof(struct ethhdr));

    int header_size =  sizeof(struct ethhdr) + iphdrlen + sizeof icmph;

    fprintf(logfile , "\n\n***********************ICMP Packet*************************\n"); 

    print_ip_header(Buffer , Size);

    fprintf(logfile , "\n");

    fprintf(logfile , "ICMP Header\n");
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Type : %d",(unsigned int)(icmph->type));

    if((unsigned int)(icmph->type) == 11)
    {
        fprintf(logfile , "  (TTL Expired)\n");
    }
    else if((unsigned int)(icmph->type) == ICMP_ECHOREPLY)
    {
        fprintf(logfile , "  (ICMP Echo Reply)\n");
    }

    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Code : %d\n",(unsigned int)(icmph->code));
    fprintf(logfile , "   |-Checksum : %d\n",ntohs(icmph->checksum));
    //fprintf(logfile , "   |-ID       : %d\n",ntohs(icmph->id));
    //fprintf(logfile , "   |-Sequence : %d\n",ntohs(icmph->sequence));
    fprintf(logfile , "\n");

    fprintf(logfile , "IP Header\n");
    PrintData(Buffer,iphdrlen);

    fprintf(logfile , "UDP Header\n");
    PrintData(Buffer + iphdrlen , sizeof icmph);

    fprintf(logfile , "Data Payload\n");    

    //Move the pointer ahead and reduce the size of string
    PrintData(Buffer + header_size , (Size - header_size) );

    fprintf(logfile , "\n###########################################################");
}

void PrintData (unsigned char* data , int Size)
{
    int i , j;
    for(i=0 ; i < Size ; i++)
    {
        if( i!=0 && i%16==0)   //if one line of hex printing is complete...
        {
            fprintf(logfile , "         ");
            for(j=i-16 ; j<i ; j++)
            {
                if(data[j]>=32 && data[j]<=128)
                    fprintf(logfile , "%c",(unsigned char)data[j]); //if its a number or alphabet

                else fprintf(logfile , "."); //otherwise print a dot
            }
            fprintf(logfile , "\n");
        } 

        if(i%16==0) fprintf(logfile , "   ");
            fprintf(logfile , " %02X",(unsigned int)data[i]);

        if( i==Size-1)  //print the last spaces
        {
            for(j=0;j<15-i%16;j++) 
            {
              fprintf(logfile , "   "); //extra spaces
            }

            fprintf(logfile , "         ");

            for(j=i-i%16 ; j<=i ; j++)
            {
                if(data[j]>=32 && data[j]<=128) 
                {
                  fprintf(logfile , "%c",(unsigned char)data[j]);
                }
                else
                {
                  fprintf(logfile , ".");
                }
            }

            fprintf(logfile ,  "\n" );
        }
    }
}
```

On Linux run the code with prefix "sudo". :)